# Disabling fast boot (system settings) programmatically

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-processing

I'm currently writing a small script that will set up a bunch of different things (settings, programs etc) on company computers. My goal is to make this happen with the least amount of human interaction.

There is this one setting that I am having a hard time finding a way to set it programmatically.

The setting I am talking about specifically is "Turn on fast startup" in `Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options\System Settings`

By default in windows 10 this box is checked, I need a way to disable it using either batch, powershell, or vbscript. (Or any other small filetype that I can run with a batch file)

[image]

Comment: @ChrisKuperstein I've tried looking through powercfg commands, some powershell commands, problem is I can't find anything related to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a batch file registry hack that should do what you want. 0=disables and 1=enables fast startup. This leaves regular hibernate alone. I use this as part of my prep script for new machines that have SSDs and thus already boot-up super fast.

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power" /v HiberbootEnabled /t reg_dword /d 0 /f
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I've marked this as correct as it more directly fixes the problem I was having than the other answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can do that with [PowerCfg](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748940(v=ws.10).aspx):

```
powercfg /hibernate OFF
```

Or [using a Group Policy](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/keithmayer/2012/11/05/supporting-windows-8-fast-startup-with-group-policy/).

Comment: You know, I almost tried that hibernate thing earlier when I found it in powercfg, but I couldn't find anything to support the idea that it would disable the proper setting. It does look like it works though, thank you.

Comment: Is there actually a way to disable fast-boot, and not disable hibernation?

Comment: @user2924019 Sorry, I don't know a way for that.

Comment: @MartinBrandl No problem. Thanks anyway.